# How to have a tap change only a single item in a ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a `ListView.builder()` to display text items from a dynamic list. The text is displayed on `Card()` widgets. I'd like tapping the text to change its appearance to and from strikeout. I've tried declaring these variables, outside `Build()`:

```
  bool isStrikeout = false;
  TextStyle _strikeout =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 16, decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough);
  TextStyle _normal = TextStyle(fontSize: 16);
```

and then, within the `Build()` method:

```
  body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: someList.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 8,
              child: ListTile(
                title: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isStrikeout = !isStrikeout;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text(
                      someList[index].text,
                      style: isStrikeout ? _strikeout : _normal,
                    ),
                  // more code here
```

The problem, of course, is that a user tapping *any* Card's text will toggle strikeout on and off for *all* Cards' texts. I only want it to happen for the tapped Card's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `List` of `bool`.

- Definition

  ```
  List<bool> strikeList = [];
  ```
- Initialize

  ```
  strikeList = List.generate(someList.length, (index)=>false);
  ```
- Usage

  ```
  body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: someList.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 8,
              child: ListTile(
                title: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      bool temp = !strikeList[index];
                     strikeList.removeAt(index);
                     strikeList.insert(index, temp);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text(
                      someList[index].text,
                      style: strikeList[index] ? _strikeout : _normal,
                    ),
                  // more code here
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You try this way

```
 int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _onSelected(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
  }
```

```
InkWell(
   onTap:() => _onSelected(index),
)
```

```
Text(
  someList[index].text,
  style: _selectedIndex == index ? _strikeout : _normal,
),
```